# Error Virtual environment Loading psycopg2 module when deploying using apache wsgi module

Tags: python, django, apache

I am deploying django using apache wsgi module and stuck at following ImproperlyConfigured error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: 
/home/uadmin/django/apache2/htdocs/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: 
undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUTF8String
```

django manage.py shell says:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 8, 1, 'final', 0)
>>> import django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
>>>
```

Settings.py has:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<pass>'
    },
    'anotherdatabase': {
        'HOST':'<IP>',
        'NAME': '<db_name>',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<pass>'
    }
}
```

Not getting why django throwing exception while deploying through wsgi, searched through git hub https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/425  and found its a known issue I tried the fix but seems not working.

Comment: Verify if connection to databases are working or not. This issue seems to be related to databases.

Comment: What's your deployment stack? This error pops up on Mac based homebrew installs with Python 2.7, for example.